# MediaQueries ignoradas a partir de certa resolução

Tags: html5, css3, aplicação-web, media-queries

Trabalhando com MediaQueries para layout responsivos, me deparei com o seguinte problema: estou configurando as resoluções tranquilamente, mas quando chego na `800px` a configuração dá `320px` e `360px`. É completamente ignorada pelo browser. O que fazer?

Com `800px`:

[image: com 800px]

Sem `800px`:

[image: sem 800px]

```
/* Smartphone em modo retrato */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .logo{
        background-size: 81px 49px !important;
        background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
        background-position: 125px 1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 360px) {
    .logo{
        background-size: 81px 49px;
        background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
        background-position: 145px 1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .logo{
        background-size: 81px 49px;
        background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
        background-position: 345px 1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    .logo{
        background-size: 81px 49px;
        background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
        background-position: 365px 1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema está na **ordem** das suas regras. Em geral, se duas regras CSS "conflitam" (i.e. ambas se aplicam ao mesmo elemento, com a mesma especificidade, e cada uma delas possui um valor diferente para uma propriedade) aquela que foi definida depois sobrescreve a que foi definida antes.

Assim, se uma regra diz `largura < 360` e outra diz `largura < 800`, uma tela com largura - digamos - `300` vai ativar ambas as regras. Se eles conflitarem, aquela que foi definida depois terá precedência.

Exemplo 1 (veja em tela cheia, redimensione a janela do browser):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Exemplo 2:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    html, body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Como pode ver, no primeiro exemplo uma vez que a tela fica menor que `800` o fundo fica verde e pronto. No segundo, ele passa de verde pra amarelo pra vermelho - uma vez que as regras mais **específicas** aparecem depois das mais gerais.