# Como se dá a precedência das regras do CSS?

Tags: css, característica-linguagem

Sei que se duas regras CSS se aplicarem ao mesmo elemento, aquela mais específica terá prioridade:

```
p { color:red; }             /* Todos os "p"s serão vermelhos... */
.umaClasse { color:yellow; } /* ...exceto os que possuem "umaClasse", que serão amarelos */
#umID { color:green; }       /* ...exceto o "umID", que será verde. */
```

E intuitivamente percebo que "o elemento com o ID X" é mais específico que "todos os elementos com a classe Y". No caso da classe, ok, podem existir mais elementos com a clase Y do que elementos com a tag Z (se a mesma classe se aplicar a várias tags diferentes), mas de todo modo como é algo definido pelo programador eu entendo que deva ter prioridade.

Também sei que se duas regras "iguais" existirem (i.e. com o mesmo seletor), a que foi definida **depois** terá prioridade. E recentemente ao tentar [responder uma outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38022/215) meus testes mostraram que o mesmo se aplica a *media queries* (i.e. se houver duas regras igualmente aplicáveis, vale mais a que apareceu depois).

Minha confusão começa nos casos em que existe mais de um critério no mesmo seletor (tipo `p.umaClasse`) - o que imagino que só aumenta sua especificidade (i.e. tem de ter a tag `p` **e** a classe `umaClasse`). Por outro lado, não vejo diferença entre `p#umID` ou simplesmente `#umID`, já que somente existe um único elemento com esse ID, ambos os seletores deveriam ser iguais, mas acaba que o primeiro tem prioridade:

```css
p#a { color: blue; }
#a { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="a">Teste</p>
```

Outra situação confusa é quando se seleciona um elemento dentro do outro:

```css
.a div p span { color:red; }
div .d { color:green; }
.b .c span { color:blue; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
      <p class="c">
        <span class="d">Teste</span>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reparei que a última regra teve precedência e, se essa for comentada, a primeira terá precedência. Por que?

- Se fizéssemos uma análise *top-down*, a primeira deveria ser a mais específica (pois a segunda e a terceira pegariam descendentes de qualquer elemento, não só das `div`s com a classe `a`);
- Se fizéssemos uma análise *bottom-up*, a segunda deveria ser a mais específica (pois a primeira e a terceira pegam qualquer `span`,  e segunda só a aquelas com a classe `d`);
- A primeira tem uma cadeia mais longa, mas a terceira estabelece mais classes. Seria isso o fator dominante? E se misturássemos classes com ids, como ficaria?

Tentei também pensar num exemplo com pseudo-classes ou atributos, mas já confundiu ainda mais minha cabeça...

Existe um meio simples de determinar, dentre duas regras CSS, qual delas terá prioridade? Se a hierarquia dos elementos é levada em conta ou não, etc.

Comment: Ai está uma pergunta bastante complicada. Tem muitas regras... +1

Comment: No último exemplo a precedência parece ter sido determinada pelo cálculo de especificidade ("Specificity Calculations"):  http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Só achei que o `abc` confunde um pouco, porque ao ver `p#a` penso em `<a>`.

Comment: @brasofilo Assim que der, edito pra usar `xyz` em vez disso (não tinha reparado nesse detalhe, valeu!)

Comment: Upsie... já tem uma resposta referenciando `abc`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A regra para definir qual vai ser considerada a mais específica, calcula, digamos assim, o *peso* de cada seletor. Para isso, são usados 4 valores, sendo eles:

A = vai ser 1, caso o estilo esteja presente em um estilo inline, caso contrário, 0
B = quantidade de seletores do atributo ID
C = quantidade de seletores de atributos, classes e pseudo-classes
D = quantidade de seletores de elementos e pseudo-elementos

Então, contando os seletores, temos no seu css como exemplo:

```
.a div p span { color:red; }  --A=0 B=0 C=1 D=3
div .d { color:green; }       --A=0 B=0 C=1 D=1
.b .c span { color:blue; }    --A=0 B=0 C=2 D=1
```

É usado o maior valor em ordem seguindo a regra que `A > B > C > D`. No caso deste exemplo na ultima regra, temos `C=2` e, por isso, ela tem precedência sobre a primeira.

Você pode ler sobre isso nas [especificações do css no site do W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: Outra referência para uma explicação detalhada: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de subir na precedência é adicionando !important ao final do atributo.

ex:

```
th.td_student{
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Aqui estava precisando sobrescrever uma declaração de cor declarada no estilo inline por um plugin.