# Como usar dois ficheiros css num html

Tags: html, css, div

Como posso usar dois ficheiros CSS num ficheiro HTML, mas um dos ficheiros CSS é apenas usado numa `div`.

Tenho um ficheiro CSS para estilar a página, mas precisava que um outro ficheiro CSS conseguisse  estilar uma `div` no meio da página.

Porque eu estou a fazer testes para usar, e eu ponho o ficheiro CSS que preciso só para a `div` primeiro, e tudo até essa `div` fica desformatado.

E se puser em segundo, tudo a seguir a essa `div` fica desformatado.
Gostaria de saber se isso é possível fazer ou não, e se sim como.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor "ponho o ficheiro css que preciso só para a div primeiro"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só acrescentar ambos no `<head>` do seu HTML:

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css1.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css2.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    ...
</head>
...
```

Se ambos os arquivos se aplicarem ao mesmo elemento, o segundo arquivo pode acabar determinando o estilo, mas isso também dependerá das [regras de precedência do CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38034).

Comment: sim eu sei. mas olhe o que eu editei na perguta

Comment: Agora eu vi. Mas aí vai depender de quais regras estão conflitando, como eu disse depende da precedência de cada uma de suas regras.

Comment: muito obrigado! era mesmo isso os dois ficheiros estavam a aplicar na div.