# Fazer float none não está funcionando

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
  <form id="formFrete" action="?" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="calculaFrete" />
    <div style="float:left;">
      <label class="labelPequeno">CEP:</label>
      <input pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" type="text" class="typeTextPequeno" id="cep" name="cep" value="<?php echo $cep; ?>" required />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="submit" value="Calcular Frete" class="btnPesquisa" />
      <a href="http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/sistemas/buscacep/" target="_blank">Não sei o CEP</a> </div>
  </form>
```

Ele se aparenta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando por resoluções abaixo de `860px` inclusive, gostaria que os `botões` `"Calcular Frete"` e o `"Não sei o cep"`, se comportassem como `bloco`.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:860px) {
 form#formFrete div {
     float:none;
 }
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: tenta por um clear:both

Comment: deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O problema neste caso é o de precedência de estilos definidos em locais ou formas diferentes, eu explico como o navegador decide qual estilo tem precedência [em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38034/como-se-d%C3%A1-a-preced%C3%AAncia-das-regras-do-css/38044#38044) caso queira conferir.

Basicamente por você ter declarado estilos inline, pelo uso do atributo `style` que tem precedência maior do que estilos definidos por css a sua regra é ignorada.

A solução simples seria usar `!important` no seu css para forçar o navegador a aplicar as regras, porém a melhor solução seria não usar o atributo `style` e fazer tudo por css

```
form#formFrete div {
    float:left;
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:860px) {
    form#formFrete div {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Desta forma poderia remover o `float:left` que estava inline no html, e como as regras em css são aplicadas na ordem em que estão no arquivo ele primeiro vai aplicar o `float:left`, mas caso a tela seja menor que 860px ele vai substituir a regra pelo `float:none`