# Como funciona a hierarquia elementos no css?

Tags: html, css, classes, style

Gostaria de saber como funciona a hierarquia no css, explico:

Digamos que na meu `style.css` eu defina para `h1, h2, h3, h4, etc.` por padrão `font-size: 12px;`, até aqui beleza...

Agora, se por exemplo eu inserir dentro de uma `class` definindo que o elemento `h1` daquela class tem `{font-size: 18px; color: #fff;}`, o elemento não deveria exibir `font-size: 18px;`? Porque várias vezes aconteceu de a `class` pegar o tamanho 12 ao invés de 18.

Espero ter sido claro na minha dúvida (e que não seja duplicata). Acredito ser bem simples a resposta rsrs

Ty

Comment: Sim é duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade e essa outra pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38034/como-se-d%C3%A1-a-preced%C3%AAncia-das-regras-do-css

Comment: @hugocsl Onde quer que vá você está lá, meu deus

Comment: @I_like_trains =D apareceu CSS eu apareço junto rss

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado hugo não consegui encontrar algo similar na hora de fazer a pergunta, mas por ser simples desconfiei que alguém já poderia ter perguntado  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segunda a documentação do [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance):

A procedência é definida em 3 níveis

**1. Importância**

Estilos com `!important` precedem todos os outros e tem maior prioridade.
Seguidos vem os estilo definidos **inline**, ou seja, no próprio elemento, dentro de `style`:

```
<div style="border: none"><div>
```

Depois a prioridade é:
Seletor por **ID**:  `#id {...}`
Seletor por nome da **class**: `.classe  {...}`
Seletor por nome da **tag**: `div {...}`

**2. Especificidade**
É medido baseado em quão específico é um seletor - quantos elementos ele pode combinar/atingir.
Tem um certo "cálculo" para ser determinado, para entender ver o link: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Mas uma forma simples de entender é: quanto mais específico um seletor for maior sua prioridade. Aqui um exemplo do link acima:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="test">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div#test span { color: green; }
div span { color: blue; }
span { color: red; }
```

Nesse exemplo, a cor será verde, pois é o seletor mais específico (`span` aninhado com uma `div`, com `ID="test"`), não importando a ordem que os seletores foram declarados.

**3. Ordem**
De uma forma básica, se os critérios acima não priorizarem a regra, segue a ordem que foram declarados

Outra ótima fonte aqui (em inglês): [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

Comment: @RicardoPortugal muito obrigado a explicação do senhor foi simples e eficaz, grande abraço!!

Comment: Só não entendi o que há de ruim na respostas que votaram negativo nela, quem votou poderia ao menos explicar a razão

Answer (score 1):

Em `CSS`, a prioridade é assim

Primeiro vem qualquer linha de `css` que tenha `!important`, que irá pôr-se sempre em primeiro lugar

O segundo fator é o `Inline Styles` ou `Estilos em Linha` que são aqueles editados na própria linha e por fim são todas as classes definidas por fora (documentos `.css`) e definição de classes na tag `<head>`