# Como aplicar o meu Css em uma tag filho

Tags: css

Dentro do meu `tableRow` há um `tableHeader` e eu quero aplicar meu `CSS` dentro do `tableHeader` Como devo prosseguir ?

```
<tr>
  <th><?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?></th>
  <th><?= $properties['empreendimento'] ?></th>
<tr>
```

Comment: da uma olhada nesse post, vai ajudar [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292641/como-funciona-a-hierarquia-elementos-no-css

Comment: não entendi bem, qual exatamente a sua dúvida? no seletor? `thead { estilos }` não funciona?

Comment: Não seria apenas colocar no CSS `th { propriedades; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar a estilização através da tag ou adicionando uma classe e referenciando ela no seu css. Veja o exemplo abaixo retirado de https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp esse site é muito bom para aprender estilização, HTML, Bootstrap etc. Espero que possa ter ajudado, se por acaso não for essa a dúvida tente editar sua pergunta e ser mais específico no que deseja:

```css
.customers {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.customers td, .customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```